# Run Flutter App on physical IOS without needing to build everytime i want to run it using XCode

Tags: ios, flutter

so i made an app that's going to be used by my self so there's no need to register the dev program on apple. My problem is, everytime I need to run the app it needs to be build by XCode 1st and keep the debug connection live.

So after the debug connection to xcode is closed, i cant open my flutter app anymore, it stops at the launch screen. Are there ways to by pass this?

Steps to reproduce :

1. Run the app using XCode
2. Stop the connection
3. Open it like a normal app in your physical phone

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Fixed, just run it on release mode instead of debug mode on xcode